# when I plug in my raspberry pi peco w into my computer the LED doesn't turn on

Tags: pi-pico-w

When I plug it into usb I can code on it, but when I power it by GND and +5V pins the LED doesn't

Comment: so, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to mean that your Raspberry Pi Pico is running when you are powering up the Pico with a laptop, it is working. But when you're using an external power supply, it is not working. Please check if your power supply is sufficient. You can see these methods of powering up the Pico with external power supplies.
https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-pico-power-methods/
For your convenience of use, you can make a Raspberry Pi Pico carrier board like this:
https://pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Raspberry_Pi_Pico_Carrier_Board_913d6468.html

Answer (score 0):

That is correct and normal operation. The LED on the Pico/Pico W is controlled by user code and will not turn on unless programmed to do so (by whatever firmware is programmed onto it).

If you would like the LED to turn on, then you have to load it with firmware that does so.